# What does it mean that the variance of a vector is = 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, variance, standard-deviation

I know that if the variance is 0, that means that all the values of a vector are the same. But I wanted to know if a special condition causes that the variance is exactly 1.

I have been told this is when $X_1,...,X_n$ have variance=1, they have the same scale, but I don't know what that means.

Comment: If a vector $v=(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$ has mean zero (that is, $v_1+v_2+\cdots+v_n=0$), then its variance is just $(1/n)(v_1^2+v_2^2+\cdots+v_n^2)$, which is just $1/n$ times the square of its length. So if two vectors (with mean zero) in an $n$-dimensional space have the same variance, then they have the same length. Maybe this is what's meant by *scale*.

Comment: I think the emphasis of what you "have been told" is not the fact that the $X_i$ all have variance $1$, but that they all have the same (non-zero) variance. Note that we can always adjust our scale such that any particular variable has variance $1$.

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments, The?